# How do I load a driver in Linux from a .run file WITHOUT restarting?

Tags: linux, command-line, drivers, linux-mint

I am on a physical machine that has an Nvidia GPU and no hdd and no ssd.
Using the USB stick, I boot Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon with an option called "-toram" (that way everything is loaded into RAM for speed, but nothing is saved upon shutdown).
I am able to use GUI to go to driver manager and use the mouse to select the [GPU driver that I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7paDa.png)

When I select the radio-button and click "Apply Changes", Linux Mint is able to download and install the driver **WITHOUT** restarting.

I was able to find the same driver on Nvidia website and I downloaded it. Its a *.run* file. I saved it to my Downloads. (in RAM)

I tried to:

```
mint@mint:~/Downloads$ chmod +x ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-495.44.run 
mint@mint:~/Downloads$ sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-495.44.run
```

[But got this message (1 of 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Ylv.png)

[Error 2 of 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEm8K.png)

(I do not want to install anything to USB drive, I just use USB drive as a boot device)

***How do I install that driver from the command line and launch it WITHOUT restarting the OS?***

Comment: There is no need to restart the machine, however you will need to restart X, you could probably work around the message by running with DISPLAY= xxxx.run

Comment: Hi @NiKiZe, I tried
```
root@mint:/home/mint/Downloads# DISPLAY=./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-495.44.run
```
That did not do anything...

Comment: You are missing the space after =

Comment: Thank you for the space suggestion. After running the command with the space, I get the same error number 1 of 2 in the image above.... https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Ylv.png

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are limitations to what you can keep running, but you don't technically have to restart. You do have to stop X server though. And this will close all GUI applications.

1. Press `Ctrl-Alt-F2` (or anything below F6) to access one of the virtual terminals.
2. Stop MDM with
   `sudo service mdm stop` Update: should be  `sudo service lightdm stop`
3. `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`
4. Install driver (make sure you use absolute path!) `sudo ./home/(your username)/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-495.44.run
5. `systemctl isolate graphical.target`
6. Restart lightdm
   `sudo service lightdm start`
7. Give X time to start! Not long usually.
8. You're still in Virtual Terminal. Your X server is probably on 7 so try `Ctrl-Alt-F7` but be prepared that it may be on F1 or even F8 or F9!

Also, you don't have to use Ctrl-Alt-Function keys. You could type `chvt 7` instead of `Ctrl-Alt-F7` for instance.

Comment: Hi @stvie, This does not work... 
When I tried to run sudo service mdm stop, I got this: Failed to stop mdm.service: Unit mdm.service not loaded.

I googled and rand sudo service lightdm stop, that worked but I still was unable to run the NVIDIA.run file. I got the following error:

Error: The Nouveau kernel driver is currently in use by your system. This driver is incompatible with the NVIDIA driver and must be disabled before proceeding.

Comment: @pavel, disable both X and other driver load at startup, or even better add whatever driver you want to the original image.

Comment: @stvie, Thank you for attempting to help but this does not make my problem go away. I do not wish to modify the usb. I wish to install a driver from the command line. I can update driver from GUI without resetting but I can not update driver from command line because I do not know how. Maybe somebody who knows can help me solve this issue. Thanks anyways!

Comment: After stopping lightdm you need to unload graphics. (i thought mint default desktop manager was mdm so I used that)      `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`    and after install  `systemctl isolate graphical.target`     based on this site:https://www.tecmint.com/change-runlevels-targets-in-systemd/amp/